# how to execute parallel psycopg2 copy_from?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a thread trying to write to a database like the following:

```
def thread(f, table, columns, conn):
  cur = conn.cursor()
  try: 
    cur.copy_from(f, table, columns)
  except:
    conn.rollback()
  else:
    conn.commit()
  finally:
    if cur is not None:
      cur.close()
```

I'd like to have multiple threads that do this but the current implementation needs a lock around it which defeats the purpose of having multiple threads.

Is there a way to do parallel `copy_from` in psycopg2?

Comment: As long as each thread has its own database connection, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ah I see, unfortunately that is not the case and that may explain why I kept getting errors. When you say `own database connection`, do you mean each has its own separate table or each calls `psycopg2.connect()` (but share teh table)? Just out of curiosity, if each thread has its own connection, how does the database keep track of different cursors and where to insert?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that each thread needs a different table. You need several database connections to the same table. Then each of these connections can `COPY` to the same table. There is no restriction from the database side.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I see. If you don't mind me asking, does the database side take care of the parallel `COPY` for me? To me, `COPY` should be done atomically, so does Postgres provide atomic copies under the hood?

Comment: I don't understand that. *You* have to launch several concurrent sessions and run `COPY`. The database does not parallelize this at all. Each `COPY` is running inside a transaction, so they are always atomic. If you want to provide atomicity across several database sessions, you need to use *two-phase commit* (but beware, this is unsafe without a distributed transaction manager).